# onClick in _.template lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have a _.template where some html is rendered with a button. Now I want to evoke a function on onClick

In my _.template

```
    <span class="input-group-btn">\
        <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick="do_search()"><span class="searching"></span></button>\
    </span>\
```

`do_search()` is implemented but when I run the code I get a run time exception `do_search()` of undefined or null reference. A new method is auto generated in file script block [dynamic]. How can I bind this method to use the existing one? I even tried `this.do_search()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onClick()` attribute can only access methods from the global (`window`) scope:

```js
function do_search() {
  alert('yey');
}

var str = '<span class="input-group-btn">\
               <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick="do_search()">\
               <span class="searching">Search</span></button>\
           </span>';
           
var compiled = _.template(str)({});

target.innerHTML = compiled;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```

Usually the event handlers are attached to this kind of templates using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
(function() {

  var str = '<span class="input-group-btn">\
               <button class="btn-primary search" type="button">\
               <span class="searching">Search</span></button>\
           </span>';

  var compiled = _.template(str)({});

  demo.innerHTML = compiled;

  var searchBtn = document.querySelector('.search');

  function do_search() {
    alert('yey');
  }

  searchBtn.addEventListener('click', do_search);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```